# Best looking administration panels for web applications

Tags: extjs

Please post a couple links to screenshots or demos to best looking administration interfaces for web applications and why do you think so.

Personally, I like what 37signals produces, also extJS based panels, though they tend to be rather slow.

Answer (score 0):

[lipsiadmin](http://rubygems.org/gems/lipsiadmin) is what you're lookin' for I guess

> Lipsiadmin is a new revolutionary admin for your projects.Lipsiadmin is based on Ext Js 2.0. framework (with prototype adapter) and is ready for Rails 2.0. This admin is for newbie developper but also for experts, is not entirely written in javascript because the aim of developper wose build in a agile way web/site apps so we use extjs in a new intelligent way a mixin of 'old' html and new ajax functions, for example ext manage the layout of page, grids, tree and errors, but form are in html code.